# why is a time difference between Wamp server and Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

i create a simple PHP page and write a below line inside it

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>
```

when i run this page,it worked fine but 
when i echo the same function inside  word press template page it has different time (default UTC) , why ?
keep in mind : both php.ini and wordpress setting timezone has the same value but the output is different.

Comment: Are you running your Wordpress site on a host?

Comment: it is on my local host

Comment: Do you even know what you're asking? W(indows), A(pache), M(ysql), P(hp) and Wordpress are 2 completely different things. Wordpress is developed in PHP and MySQL and may run on apache/nginx and windows/linux.

Comment: Check if the timezone is really the same. You can get the set default time zone with: [date_default_timezone_get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)

Comment: @Daan i setup wordpress on my local host, i am beginner in wordpress , instead of your such words ,you may said a useful information related to my question, any way thanks .

Comment: @enricog , the setting of both are the same , it printed correctly without using wordpress , the problem appeared when i use the same function in wordpress template page

Comment: Go to wp-admin -> setting -> general -> Timezone. You can set your time zone from here.

Comment: thanks @hardiksolanki ,  i already do this step , same problem

Answer (score 0):

Solved after open wp-setting.php and changed the below line to the desired timezone , thanks all

```
date_default_timezone_set( 'UTC' );
```